# next js fetch fails on componentdidmount

Tags: reactjs

I can't even get any result because cors error with class definition extends react component.

But if I try it as const function, I can get result with async fetch.

Why? this not working

```
export default class extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://169.63.69.227:5050/api/auth')
            .then(response=>response.json())
            .then(response=>alert(response))
    }
}
```

and this example is working good

https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages/fetching-batman-shows

Comment: You have a CORS error?

Comment: yes when i try in componentdidmount...

Comment: It works in the link you provided because the code there is run from the server and CORS is client-side.

Comment: Did you configure the server to accept requests from a different origin?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli How can i do server render with a component class rather than stateless component?, i will need states etc

Comment: https://github.com/barron9/hellonext/blob/master/pages/index.js, i guess Index.getinitialprops renders serverside, but methods in component rrender in clientside